Change the value of RelayState in SAML pac4j in vertx
I am using vertx with pac4j-saml dependency to implement user authentication by SP.
I am trying to change the value of relayState that sends the authNRequest by changing its value in the web session. For this I use the SessionStore method (I understand that this object is to deal with the user's web session):
sessionStore.set(WebContext context, String key, Object value);

By specifying as key "samlRelayState " and as value the value that I want to put to the relayState I understand that the relayState value of the web session can be changed and therefore the one that is sent with the authNRequest.
How do I get the WebContext that is using the pac4j-saml dependency? Because when I use the WebContext method it is null since it does not exist in the class where I am calling it.

In Vert.x, the webContext is a VertxWebContext built from the RoutingContext and the SessionStore.
